# Querying within a time range in mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongo database where I'm storing a date and time in separate fields (I do not have the ability to change this setup). Googling around, I found examples of people querying dates and times by breaking fields up into 2 parts, 1 for date and 1 for time, like:

```
{"dateField": {"d": "06/18/2012" "t": "12:00:00 AM"}}
{"timeField": {"d": "06/18/2012" "t": "12:07:10 PM"}}
```

I've seen people (and have been able to myself) query the date portion:

```
db.collection.find({"dateField.d": {"$gte": "06/18/2012"}})
```

My problem is I cannot get accurate results trying the same thing with time:

```
db.collection.find({"timeField.t": {"$gte": "12:00:00 PM"}})
```

Is there a specific way I should be formatting my time data to query it? Or is there a better way for storing time data so that I can query just the time (without it being dependent on a date)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store data in a real Date format or as numbers. When you are doing those searches  the comparison is using [lexicography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicography) order which is not what you want. If you do want to use strings you should use one of the [ISO formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) where it works.

Comment: That sounds like a bad way to go [storing dates as strings].

Comment: Thanks, converting to ISO formats worked. @monksy While I'd prefer to store dates and times as objects, the issue is that with date information and time information being kept in separate fields, I need something that's time and time only. Unfortunately, every object representation I could find combined time with a date (which may or may not still be the correct date as time passes and data gets changed).